# Using SSRS join on the parameter passed in the report

Tags: join, reporting-services

Using SSRS, If I've created a data set using code (I've got the following union statement). What I would like to do is to say - only return the data of the one - where the parameter passed (is customer_no) basically where a.customer_no = customer_no that is passed as a parameter. But I don't think I'm doing this accurately.

```
select  reservation_no,
        customer_no,
        'GT Adult' as 'price_type',
        a.adult as pt, 
        (select b.adult from LT_CHC_TOURS_RSV_PRICE b) as current_price
FROM    LV_CHC_TOURS_RSV_DATA a
WHERE   a.customer_no = Fields!customer_no.Value

union

select  reservation_no,
        customer_no,
        'GT Senior/Student' as 'price_type',
        a.senior_student,
        (select b.senior_student from LT_CHC_TOURS_RSV_PRICE b) as current_price
from    LV_CHC_TOURS_RSV_DATA a
WHERE   a.customer_no = Fields!customer_no.Value
```

What do I replace `Fields! customer_no.Value` with?

Comment: What are you trying to represent with Fields!customer_no.Value?    Is it a field in another dataset, or is it a report parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Dataset query, change `Fields!customer_no.Value` to `@SomeParameterName`.

Then, still in the dataset, go to the parameters tab, and map the dataset parameter to your report parameter.